# Is $\mathbb{R^+}$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I can't seem to violate any of the axioms, *if* I take the number $0$ to be in $\mathbb{R^+}$.  Then the additive and multiplicative identities are in the set, the numbers all have a multiplicative inverse, etc.

However, I was told that I was wrong.  What have I overlooked?

Thanks

Comment: If by $\mathbb{R}^+$ you mean the positive reals, then you wouldn't have $-1$.

Comment: Are additive inverses contained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What is 10's inverse under addition?

Comment: Ahhh I see - thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

What about the equation $x+7=2$?

Answer (score 0):

@ Everyone: What if we use $\log$ to identify points with whole $\mathbb{R}$ and then do both addition and multiplication there.